# How can I convert a string into a function in Python?

Tags: string, csv, python-3.x, type-conversion

I have to deal with csv image data from a camera which exports the data with a header.  In that header is a simple function for converting CCD counts into power density.  This equation includes both the dark offset level as well as a calibration factor.  Here is an example from one line of an image file:

> Power Density,=,(n - 232) * 4.182e-005 W/cm^2

Notice the commas.  The csv header can be expected to have the same structure each time with different constants for dark level (232) and power density conversion (4.182e-005).

What I would like to be able to do is grab the last cell, strip off the units at the end (W/cm^2), and use what is left to define a function in Python.  Something like

```
f = lambda n: '(n - 232) * 4.182e-005'
```

Is it possible to do so?  If so, how?

Comment: I would try to preprocess string a little bit (e.g. get rid of W/cm^2, commas etc.) and then try to [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html) it.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of `tokenize`.  I've already got the preprocessing done so I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` and `exec`, which use `compile`, are both ways to dynamically convert code as text to a compiled function.  If you dynamically create a new function, you only need to do the conversion once.

```
row = "Power Density,=,(n - 232) * 4.182e-005 W/cm^2".split(',')
expr = row[2].replace( ' W/cm^2', '')
# f = eval("lambda n:" + expr)  # based on your original idea
exec("def f(n): return " + expr)  # more flexible
print(f(0))
# -0.00970224
```

The lambda eval and def exec have the same result, other than f.**name**, but as usual, the def form is more flexible, even if the flexibility is not needed here.

The usual caveats about executing untrusted code apply.  If you are working with photo files not your own and were worried about an adversary feeding you a poisoned file, then indeed you might want to tokenize expr and check that is only has the tokens expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it using `eval`, but I expect that it isn't very pythonic so I would still be interested in seeing other answers.

Here `row` is the row of interest from a `csv.reader` object, i.e. the same string I posted in the question divided at the commas.

```
# Strip the units from the string
strng = row[2].replace( ' W/cm^2', '')
# Define a function based on the string
def f( n):
    return eval( strng)
# Evaluate a value
print( f( 0))
# Returns: -0.00970224
```